# Probability of choosing any real number in the range $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability, infinity

Basically I want to give a counter argument (if possible) to the statement:

"It is unlikely to randomly pick any real number in the interval $[0,1]$"

The statement implies that there is a small probability. So if you could either prove that the probability is $0$, or if you can prove that you cant define the probability in the first place, then that should be enough to make a counter argument?

I've done a bunch of reading and there seems to be multiple ways to tackle this, like measure theory, logical possibility, conceptual possibility etc.... Some guy said that the probability of choosing one specific number on a uniform distribution is $0$, but here we are talking about infinitely many numbers in the range $[0,1]$.

I'm assuming there is someone smarter than me here who knows this stuff, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by the quoted sentence. Do you specifically mean the same as the probability of choosing a specific number on a uniform distribution? For ex. let $X \sim \text{Uniform}[0,1] \Rightarrow P(X= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=0$. Do you mean this? Or something like $Y \sim \text{Uniform}[-\infty, \infty]$ (which, I think, is impossible) ?

Comment: Yea the second case, you choose a random real number, (- ∞ , ∞ ), can you then say it is unlikely that this number will be in the interval [0,1]? Or is it impossible to have a uniform distribution on the interval (- ∞ , ∞ )? I don't know if this is a meaningful distinction but I'm not asking what the probability is to pick one specific number on the interval, more like what the measure of that interval [0,1] is compared to (- ∞ , ∞ ) (maybe).

Comment: Some thoughts about the topic: http://bactra.org/weblog/635.html

Answer (score 4):

If i understood correctly, then you are asking wheter there exists a uniform probability distribution $P$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and if so, what is $P([0,1])$.

The answer is no. Suppose however towards a contradiction, that such a measure exists.
Now by basic probability axioms we can write
$$P(\mathbb{R}) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}P([k,k+1))$$
since $\{[k,k+1) \: : \: k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a (countable) partition of $\mathbb{R}$. If the distribution is uniform, then $P([k,k+1))=P([n,n+1))$ for all $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so we have two cases to cover:

$$P([k,k+1))=\alpha > 0  \Rightarrow P(\mathbb{R})= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \alpha = \infty$$
and
$$P([k,k+1))= 0  \Rightarrow P(\mathbb{R})= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} 0 = 0$$
but both cases give a contradiction, since we assumed $P$ to be a probability measure.

Answer (score -4):

It's simple. A single real number is a single point. [0,1] has lenght 1. [0,1/2] has lenght 1/2 so the probability of picking a number out of that interval is 1/2/1=1/2. A point has no (measurable) lenght. So the probability of picking it is 0 /1=0. Also picking out any rational number is zero, regardless of the fact that there is an infinite number of them, chances of landing on a rational number on a real line are 0. Because each single rational has on its own no measurable lenght. Sets like all rationals in  [0,1], have no defined lenght because they have discontinuities, lots of them, they are missing all the irrationals like pi, square of 2 etc. Therefore only reals are smooth and complete enough to have a meaningful definition of lenght defined on their intervals.

Comment: According to you logic the chances of landing on an irrational number is also $0$.

Comment: @user yes, that's correct

Comment: This is not correct, if you do not have in mind a particular number.

Comment: @user what does it matter?

Comment: @Ezio If you have an argument saying the probability $p$ to land in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is zero *and* the probability $q$ to land in $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is zero, then you have a problem. Since we must have $p+q=1$.

Comment: Where did I say that?

Comment: In the comments above. "According to you logic the chances of landing on an irrational number is also 0" $\leadsto$ "@user yes, that's correct". @Ezio

Comment: This is also what your answer suggests, since your argument "sets like all rationals in [0,1], have no defined lenght because they have discontinuities, lots of them" also applies to irrationals.

Comment: Probability of q is 1

Comment: The probability of picking a rational number is 0 and 1 for picking an irrational one. It has to do with the measure of the set

Comment: I didn't say users comment was right

Comment: @Ria obviously..

Comment: Ezio, your argument above -- how does it *not* apply to irrationals? "*Because each single rational has on its own no measurable lenght. [...] Sets like all rationals in [0,1], have no defined length because they have discontinuities, lots of them*" As written, it also applies to them, and therefore must be wrong as it leads to the contradiction pointed out above.

Comment: Firstly Irrationals don't have lots of 'holes', not as many as rationals!! .Secondly a set of irrationals is NOT like a set of rationals. Read carefully.

Comment: I have read your post. It is not rigorous, the argument is not convincing. It's useful as intuition, but it's not a proof (far from it), and can be interpreted naturally and easily to lead to contradictions.

Comment: I gave it only to make an intuitive point and on the formal mathematical level of the question..

Comment: There are no contradictions in it.

Comment: "... chances of landing on a rational number on a real line are 0. Because each single rational has on its own no measurable lenght." Now replace both words "rational" with "irrational". Do you see a contradiction?

Comment: Do you see where I said this applies only to sets like rationals?

Comment: No, I do not see it. I see only that your main argument is "Because each single *** has on its own no measurable lenght."

Comment: I don't see a contradiction. Sets of individual points have no measurable lenght because points have no measurable lenght, unless points are joined together into nice and smooth enough intervals or subsets of reals.

Comment: I accept that you don't see a contradiction.

Comment: There is no contradiction don't care what you accept

Comment: How **exactly** do you join *irrationals* "together into nice and smooth enough intervals or subsets of reals". What does it even mean for a subset to be "nice and smooth"?

Comment: It means to be measurable. What it means precisely? Well for that u use some precise definition of a measure.

Comment: ... the set of rationals *is* measurable. You're just throwing words around at that point. (I'm going to stop answering.)

Comment: Set of irrationals is measurable yes so? I'm just saying it as it is..

Comment: *Set of irrationals is measurable yes so? I'm just saying it as it is..* $\leadsto$ Oh  gosh the set of irrationals **is measurable too**. /end

Comment: It has to be otherwise probability of picking one would be zero..